# How the user to pick the amount of folders on a desktop to be created with numeric names using applescript?

Tags: directory, applescript

I'm trying to allow the user to pick how many folders they want to create on the desktop.  The desired file format is 00,01,02,03..10,11,12,13,14...99.  I feel like I'm close to creating the folders but I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
set targetFolder to desktop
repeat
    set subCount to text returned of (display dialog "How many Folders?" default answer 1)
    try
        if subCount ≠ "" then
            subCount as integer
            exit repeat
        end if
    end try
end repeat

repeat with i from 1 to subCount
    tell application "Finder" to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:i}
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Generally speaking, it's better to use System Events.app than the Finder (the Finder is pickier about file path specifications, and has a tendency to hang at times), and if you want zero-padded folder names you have to convert your index integer to a string.

```
repeat
    set subCount to text returned of (display dialog "How many Folders?" default answer 1)
    try
        set subCount to subCount as integer
        exit repeat
    on error
        display alert "The value must be an integer"
    end try
end repeat

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with idx from 1 to subCount
        make new folder at desktop folder with properties {name:my zeroPad(idx - 1)}
    end repeat
end tell

on zeroPad(a_num)
    return text -2 through -1 of ("0000" & a_num as string)
end zeroPad
```

Comment: Perfect Ted!  Thank you once again!